# Getting TypeError on greater than less than

Tags: python

I'm getting an error on if `if (num1 <= 0):` I have looked for a solution, the error im getting is:

> " if (num1 <= 0): TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: The error is telling you that `num1` is a string not a number. You can convert it to an integer (if that's appropriate here) with `int(num1) <= 0`

Comment: Maybe edit your question to include the line where `num1` is defined. If it is via `input()` for example, it will have to be converted using `int` as mentioned. For simple debugging, I also often throw in a `print(num1)` line before the line that generates the error, as a reality check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that num1 is an int type. It looks like num1 is a string. You can check the type of num1 by running type(num1). You can't compare a string to an integer. For example "this" >= 2 doesn't make sense. Good luck and continue learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is self explanatory, you're trying to evaluate a string and an int. Make sure the value inside num1 is an int